# ¿Como puedo recorrer un subconjunto de datos dentro de un group by?

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, bucles, group-by

hace poco empecé a programar y estoy intentando recorrer un subconunto de datos agrupados por id para encontrar si alguno de los id's fue marcado con algún  código específico y luego, si es que fue marcado con el código y a la vez no es el último código con el que fue marcado que se haga un comentario.
Si esto ocurre, pandas exporta un archivo comentando los id's que tienen el codigo buscado.

```
grouped = df1.groupby('id')
c = 001
for x in grouped:
   if c in x[1]["CODE"] and c != x[1]['CODE'].values[len(x[1]['CODE'])-1]:
           n = x[0]
           for t in range(0, len(list(df2["OT"]))-1):
                if n == df2["OT"][t]: 
                    df2["Comentarios"][t] = "Comentario"
```

Al parecer el problema está en que no logro comparar realmente los CODE del id con el código que quiero buscar, si no que estoy comparando el código que quiero buscar con el numero de iteración del loop. 
Si me pudieran ayudar lo agradecería!

Comment: Hola joaquinl96, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Podrías agregar un pequeño ejemplo de df1 y la salida esperada para ese ejemplo? Eso facilitaría mucho dar una respuesta a la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, si, df1 es un archivo excel que contiene todos los códigos con los que un id ha sido marcado, tiene la columna id y la columna CODE, claramente l id se repite tantas veces como códigos tenga hasta que se pasa al siguiente id.
la salida esperada es que se modifique df2 (un excel que contiene dos columnas, ids y comentarios) y en la columna de comentarios se escriba un comentario para cada id que cumpla las dos condiciones del if (que tenga dentro de sus códigos el código buscado y que si lo tiene, que no sea el último)

Comment: El archivo final entonces tendría las mismas filas, solo que una columna más con los comentarios ¿No? ¿`df_idem["OT"]` contendría los códigos a buscar?

Comment: nono, el df2 tiene solo los id(ot para el caso de ese archivo) y una columna para comentarios, no tiene los codigos